# Qt3D custom mesh "Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap" runtime error

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I made a custom mesh class inherited `Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer` to draw lines  in Qt3D and use it in the same way as `Qt3DExtras::QShpereMesh` or others. Here the source( [.h](https://github.com/ikvasir/Real_World_Algorithms/blob/master/AlgorithmsVisualisationQt/qlinemesh.h) ,  [.cpp](https://github.com/ikvasir/Real_World_Algorithms/blob/master/AlgorithmsVisualisationQt/qlinemesh.cpp) )
And on test with single line creation everithing as i expected, line creates and destroy without an error. But if do test with `std::vector<Qt3DCore::QEntity*>` and put to it 100 `Qt3DCore::QEntity*` and add them line as a component i have heap error.([here test project](https://github.com/ikvasir/Real_World_Algorithms/tree/master/QLineMesh_test))

Version of Qt:6.1.0.

In Visual Studio 2019 CE with DEBUG 64bit build the runtime error message is:

`HEAP[QLineMesh_test.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 0000013BF0630000, 0000013BF522D060 ) QLineMesh_test.exe has triggered a breakpoint.` 
and VS  points to breakpoint line in file `debug_heap.cpp`:

```
// This function is provided for backwards compatibility only.  It returns TRUE
// if the given block points to an allocation from the OS heap that underlies
// this CRT debug heap.  Back when the CRT used its own OS heap (prior to Dev10),
// this function would thus also tell you whether the block was allocated by this
// debug heap.  Now, it just tells you whether the block was allocated by some
// debug heap.
extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(void const* const block)
{
    if (!block)
        return FALSE;

    return HeapValidate(__acrt_heap, 0, header_from_block(block));  ///<-----breakpoint here on HeapValidate
}
```

In VS RELEASE 64bit build  breakpoint is in `qarraydata.h` at `QArrayData::reallocateUnaligned` function call.

In QtCreator with MSVC2019 64bit and minGW64-bit builds program terminated after same behaviour but without such deep explanation.

May be the error happen in function which generate the vertex data of mesh and put it to `QByteArray` for later usage in `Qt3DCore::QBuffer`.The fragment code of function from  [here](https://github.com/ikvasir/Real_World_Algorithms/blob/master/AlgorithmsVisualisationQt/qlinemesh.cpp):

```
inline void QLineMesh::generateVertexData()
{
    ...
    vertex_buf.clear();
    
    vertex_buf.resize((3 + 3) * 6 * sizeof(float));
    float* possitions = reinterpret_cast<float*>(vertex_buf.data());
    int index = 0;

    for (auto& v : vertices)
    {
        possitions[index++] = v.x();
        possitions[index++] = v.y();
        possitions[index++] = v.z();
    }

};
```

I can`t imagene how the heap can be affected by this mesh creation class if it's just store  pointers and logic to how to manage it.

UPDATE:
In Qt 5.15.2 everithing works as expected without errors. Source in question support both versions.

Comment: This is probably a bit beyond Stack Overflow when it needs to take the project and debug. There so many unsafe moments through your code that pointing all out is some work. I do use Qt 3D with Qt 5.12 and yes it takes steady hand and very safe C++ practices to create own 3D Geometry. Mind the example above: some fixed size buffer reserved for those `position` items and the it the buffer filled from vector `vertices` of unknown size. Better create some very strict helper to prevent any underflow/overflow. To me the problem is around those lines.

Comment: I'v add `if ((vertices.size() * 3) == (vertex_buf.size()/sizeof(float)))` checking but i see the same errrors. This is my first such complicated task with Qt so in general i just wanna find the way how to debug it. And when i wrote it i hoped that somebody have same types of errors in working with Qt3D.

Comment: Start with most primitive single thing to present and then add more and see. Always enforce the safety with such type of buffer access. Asserts etc.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! As a result of many hours of trying to solve the problem, partial and complete rewriting of the code, I decided to compile everything in the 5.15.2 version of the Qt. And everything works here without any errors as expected! After all, the examples and manuals that I was guided by were written in Qt5! Maybe later when Qt6 will be LTS and with official docs and examples about I will return to it.

Comment: Nothing new if they screwed up Qt3D again. We are the commercial customer and talk to Qt Company about many issues like that. They offer workaround etc.